# Python XML question

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have an XML document as a `str`. Now, in the XSD `<foo>` is unbounded, and while most of the time there is only 1, there *COULD* be more. I'm trying to use `ElementTree`, but am running into an issue:

```
>>> from xml.etree.ElementTree import fromstring
>>> 
>>> xml_str = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
... <foo>
...     <bar>
...         <baz>Spam</baz>
...         <qux>Eggs</qux>
...     </bar>
... </foo>"""
>>> # Try to get the document
>>> el = fromstring(xml_str)
>>> el.findall('foo')
[]
>>> el.findall('bar')
[<Element 'bar' at 0x1004acb90>]
```

Clearly, I need to loop through the `<foo>`s, but because `<foo>` is at the root, I can't. Obviously, I could create an element called `<root>` and put `el` inside of it, but is there a more *correct* way of doing this?

Comment: Can someone give this question a more descriptive title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each XML document is supposed to have exactly one [root element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element). You will need to adjust your XML if you want to support multiple `foo` elements.

Comment: @orokusaki: as I understood your problem, you didn't have multiple root elements, but rather wanted to find all `foo` elements, whether they occurred as root element or elsewhere in the tree. If you actually had multiple root elements (which seems likely because you accepted this answer) you might consider rephrasing the question for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Alas, wrapping the element in an `ElementTree` with `tree = ElementTree(el)` and trying `tree.findall('//foo')` doesn't seem to work either (it seems you can only search "beneath" an element, and even if the search is done from the full tree, it searches "beneath" the root). As ElementTree doesn't claim to really implement xpath, it's difficult to say whether this is intended or a bug.

Solution: without using [lxml](http://lxml.de) with full xpath support (`el.xpath('//foo')` for example), the easiest solution would be to use the [Element.iter()](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter) method.

```
for foo in el.iter(tag='foo'):
    print foo
```

or if you want the results in a list:

```
list(el.iter(tag='foo'))
```

Note that you can't use complex paths in this way, just find all elements with a certain tagname, starting from (and including) the element.

Comment: ha, that ``tree = ElementTree(el)`` bit was my exact first thing I tried when I ran into the issue (without luck, of course). Thanks for the new approach, though (the ``el.iter`` bit).